# Join tables in different schemas/dbs

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Could anyone please let me know how I can perform the below in SnowFlake?

1. How can I pull data from two different tables in different schemas in the same database object in SnowFlake using a query? The two tables have a common field to join them.
2. How can I pull data from two different tables in different schemas in different database objects in SnowFlake using a query? the two tables have a common field to join them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to achieve using [(fully-)qualified names](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/name-resolution.html#object-name-resolution):

```
SELECT *
FROM schema_name_1.tab_1 AS t1
JOIN schema_name_2.tab_2 AS t2
  ON t1.col = t2.col;

SELECT *
FROM database_name_1.schema_name_1.tab_1 AS t1
JOIN database_name_2.schema_name_2.tab_2 AS t2
  ON t1.col = t2.col;
```